# ng-disabled doesnt disable date picker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-ngmodel

I am implementing a simple date picker for an expiration date that needs to be disabled if the never checkbox is checked. Using the ng-model concept I have implemented it as below :

```
<label>Click me to toggle: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" /></label><br />
  <input type="date" name="date" ng-disabled="checked" />
```

For some reason this doesnt work in my project and so I pasted this in a stackblitz project to see if that works. Unfortunately it doesnt work there as well

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sstour-tjelcz?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Can someone please tell me what it is that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: ng-model="checked" is used for angularJs not angular+2

Answer (score 1):

You should use proper `[(ngModel)]` and `[disabled]` `Input`s / `Output`s.

Please read about [NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel).

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sstour-h6bydk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Answer (score 1):

With **angular2** or higher you must use this syntax

Ts :

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = "Tour of Heroes";
  author = "Sourabh Sriom"
  checked = false;
}
```

Html

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a>
</nav>

<label>Click me to toggle: <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checked" /></label>
  <input type="date" name="date" [disabled]="checked" />

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-messages></app-messages>
```

For more info : https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel